# What are these fuses?

Tags: circuit-breaker

Just come across a fuse box that I've never seen before. The box looks like this:

> [image]

They are like light-bulb-type things that host a fuse inside of them. The fuse looks like this:

> [image]

They work similarly to light bulbs too, with caps that screw in.

Any idea what these fuses are?

Comment: Just do **not** stick your fingers in the holes... made at a time when commonsense was widely available... :)

Comment: There was no such time, and "common sense" continues to be whatever I know and you don't. :P

Comment: The standard (older) fuse type here in Norway...  There are also automatic-fuses that can fit into the same bottom-socket (but then without the glass-cap).  The colour tells the amp.  https://www.clasohlson.com/no/Elektro/Elektroinstallasjon/Sikringer-og-bunnskruer/c/1698

Comment: There was certainly a time when there was seen to be much less need to protect people from their own stupidity than there is today.

Comment: As a kid I used to open them after they blew (which they did frequently) and collect the nice quartz sand.

Comment: @PeterGreen:  Anything that can be done by stupidity can also be done by accident.  Even if you know better than to stick your finger in an open fuse socket, there's nothing in this world that will prevent even a careful person from making a mistake.

Comment: @JRE That's why you usually don't leave them open. When servicing machines, you even [stick dummies in](https://shopdelta.eu/obrazki2/le-606725_img7_d.jpg), so others don't accidentally put a real one in.

Answer (score 15):

This is not necessarily a Weber product, but certainly an IEC 60269 "D type II" fuse, quite common in Europe. The "D" is short for "DIAZED", a registered trademark of Siemens AG. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60269#D_type_fuses for more details.

The colored button (red, blue) in the middle indicates the rated current (red = 10 amps, blue = 20 amps, see Wiki page above), and pops off when the fuse breaks (clearly visible through the glass window, so you know immediately what happened). To replace a broken fuse, unscrew the cap, and don't stick your finger into the hole (the whole thing is otherwise safe).

A side remark (in case you do not speak french): The labels read

- cuisinière (left column) = electric stove
- lumière (middle column) = light
- chauffage = heating
- frigo = fridge
- machine à laver = washing machine

Comment: Good old bottle fuses. Can be replaced by a nail, in times of trouble (all liability on the idiot that does so, though). As a further comment, the stove has a 20 amp breaker for each phase, so must be a bit larger than the common household variant.

Answer (score 8):

Weber DT II fuses.  Sometimes called "bottle" fuses.

[Weber Fuse Catalog](https://www.italweber.it/catalogue/product.aspx?c=0008005202390508&i=1221010)